# Can thymeleaf print html code?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a object "item" from SpringMVC model.

if "item" equals 1, I want to print:

```
<input .../>
```

else, I want to print:

```
<span.../>
```

How can I achieve that?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with a switch statement...

```
<th:block th:switch="${item}">
  <input th:case="1" />
  <span th:case="*" />
</div>
```

Or multiple if/unless

```
<input th:if="${item == 1}" />
<span th:unless="${item == 1}" />
```

You can put it straight into html with th:utext, but I don't think it's a very good idea (as you can't use th:statments in the generated html, and you can't validate as a document etc...).

```
<th:block th:utext="${item == 1 ? '<input .../>' : '<span.../>'}" />
```